# Proof of Continuity on an Interval

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

I'm having trouble proving that the function below is continuous on [1,e]

$$  \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n3^n} ln(x) $$

Many answers I've seen already involve derivatives (which I cannot use) or just appear to have incomplete or incorrect answers.

Any help outlining a proof?  I'm allowed to use the fact that the natural logarithm is continuous and increasing without proof.

Comment: You could argue that this series converges uniformly on $[1,e]$ (e.g. by Weierstrass M test or something else), so because the partial sums are continuous the uniform limit must also be continuous.

Comment: Well. $\sum\frac{1}{n3^n}\ln x= \text{const}\cdot \ln x$.

Comment: Is it $x$ or $n$ ?